# Which scripture is this shloka from? (etasya kṛtakṛta vatāt kṣāstra nivṛtite)

Tags: scripture, vedas, mantras, reference-request, shloka

I am trying to identify which scripture this sloka is from ? I came across this from a lecture:

> etasya kṛtakṛta vatāt kṣāstra nivṛtite
> एतस्य कृतकृत वतात क्षास्त्र  निवृतिते

```
एतस्य (etasya): Of this
कृतकृत (kṛtakṛt): Accomplished, fulfilled
वतात (vatāta): As one desires, by one's own will
क्षास्त्र (kṣāstra): Sorrows
निवृतिते (nivṛtite): In the cessation, relief, freedom
```

Researching online so far I have no success.